# How use dnf command without updating the repositories?

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf

When I use the `dnf` command, it starts to update repositories and it takes a while, especially when the OS is outdated. Sometimes I need to use `dnf info` or something like that and I don't need it to be updated. How can I use it in a way it does not search for update?

Comment: An alternative option is to learn the `rpm` commands that are local-only, *e.g.* `rpm -qi packagename` to get the info on an _installed_ package.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `--cacheonly` (or `-C`) option; this will use the system cache only, without updating it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--setopt=metadata_expire=never` never mark metadata as expired, you may get old version of package or download failed (old package may be deleted in repo server).

```bash
dnf install --setopt=metadata_expire=never <package>
```

Using `--cacheonly` aka `-C` only use cache, if you never `dnf install` or `dnf download` the package before to cache it, this will fail. And this swicth never updates metadata for sure.

```bash
dnf install -C <package>
```